# Programmatically pin the application to taskbar and Adding Custom message in flyouts in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is it possible to pin the application Programmatically in task bar during app launch?

Also, Is there any way to add custom message to flyouts?

Answer (score 1):

1. As Vladislav said, there's currently no API to pin/unpin your app to taskbar but the support is coming with Fall Creators Update - [Pin your app to the taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/pin-to-taskbar).
2. If you mean jump lists - items shown in the flyout after right clicking on the icon in taskbar or Start, take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no API to pin/unpin your app to taskbar
2. I am not sure if you mean flyout or dialog, but you can add custom message to both of them :

Flyout is a usual XAML container, you can add any UI elements inside it.

[Complete tutorial for dialogs](https://reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-10-xaml-tips-messagedialog-and-contentdialog)